# installing compiled code locally in OS X from Xcode

Tags: c, xcode, macos, ide

I'm trying to learn program development in OS X so I downloaded and installed Xcode(4.6.3) onto a Pro (10.8.4). To get my arms around the Xcode IDE I created a command line project and copied into it a C program (32-bit code last compiled on AIX) from my many years developing in C on Unix/Linux. After fixing a few type mismatches (long long off_t in certain system calls) this program builds and runs without warnings or errors.  I can build for running, archive or debug; no problems with the source code or the builds. However, now I want to install this utility on my Mac and after searching through every menu thread looking for "install", I cannot see how to do this. I asked this question on Apple Developers forum and nada answers. I have no intention of distributing through the Apple store or otherwise so this notion of asking Apple for some sort of signing certificate is a "non-starter". I should not need Apple's permission to install a program I write in Xcode on my own Mac, yet there appears to be no way to do this. I would expect to see an 'install' action in the 'Product' menu but none is present. Either I omitted some step in the workflow or I'm missing something very obvious in the IDE. A simple explanation of 'install' from Xcode is all I'm looking for. Thanks in advance for any insights.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a command line tool, can't you just copy the binary to /usr/local/bin or something? Poke around in the build and find the binary. `sudo cp binary dest_dir`.If it's a "real" application, `sudo cp -r MyApp.app /Applications`.

If you add the line `system("pwd")` to `main()` it will tell you where Apple is hiding he binary. Then use the above instructions.

Apple's hiding of the build, ( in mine it's `/Users/crb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/junk-gitnsfvokhzgooeleylfwyhokkih/Build/Products/Debug` ) has always annoyed me. No doubt there is a way in Xcode to tell it where to put the build, I just haven't bothered looking for it.

Comment: In the Product navigator I found a fully qualified path to the compiled binary.  It does have a magic number in it, as in: /Users/carly/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ftlhash-bmvdtmtwkzokenfidxierdhdumkj/Build/Products/Debug/ftlhash. I was able to manually cp this path to my preferred directory and run the program from the command line. But that is a dumb hack with an IDE that is as complete as Xcode. There must be an Xcode way to do this.